# Is it possible to insert a bibtex reference into a nomenclature entry?

Tags: bibtex, nomenclature

I'm trying to create a list of symbols, and the nomenclature package is working pretty well. However, I can't seem to figure out how to insert references (from bibtex) into a nomenclature entry.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature   
\begin{document}

Text, text, text. $\chi _E$
\nomenclature{$\chi _E$}{Electric susceptibility; blah; see, e.g., \citet{reference}.}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to define `\citet` (I assumed you intended natbib here)

Then you need to run pdflatex, then makeindex for nomencl, then pdflatex again, then run bibtex to generate the reference from the citation that nomenc added then run pdflatex twice more to resolve cross references.

tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl,natbib}
\makenomenclature   
\begin{document}

Text, text, text. $\chi _E$
\nomenclature{$\chi _E$}{Electric susceptibility; blah; see, e.g., \citet{reference}.}

\printnomenclature
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{zz}
\end{document}
```

zz.bib:

```
@article{reference,
title={zzz},
author={Zzz}
}
```

so command sequence is

```
pdflatex file
makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls
pdflatex file
bibtex file
pdflatex file
pdflatex file
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was running latex/bibtex an appropriate number of times along with makeindex -- the .nlo file needs to have the reference updated before you create the .nls file.